# How to migrate from qmail to postfix?

Tags: postfix, migration, email

I am looking for a clear and detailed guide to do the migration on Linux but I could not find anything useful. So appreciate your hints.

Comment: What mailbox format are you using? What size installations? In-house, or with outside customers using the mail? There isn't a one-size-fits-all migration plan for something like that.

Answer (score 5):

1. Find out how qmail is configured.
2. Read the postfix documentation to find out how to create this specific config in postfix and how to work around things that might not be possible anymore.
3. Configure postfix accordingly.
4. Test it and fix issues.
5. You are done.

Really, configuring mail is such a diverse and complicated topic that a migration guide will either only cover the most basic scenarios or be filled with so many ifs and whens that it's not clear and concise anymore. And since you need to learn and understand postfix configuration anyway, do it while recreating your old config.